# identifier expected geting value from web.config

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i am reading value from web.config and want to redirect the user the url that is in my web.config . But when i try to access the key this is giving me error of `identifier expected`. Below is my web.config and code part . Can you please explane me what is i am doing mistake here .

```
<appSettings>  
    <add key="SECURE_URL" value="https://google.com"/>
  </appSettings>
```

This is my code

```
 Protected Sub bttSearch1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles bttSearch1.Click
     Dim StrValue As String  = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SECURE_URL"]

      Response.Redirect("StrValue" + "/park/notice/payment.aspx")
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are using VB.NET, you do not use square brackets (["SECURE_URL"]) to access an index, but normal brackets ( ("SECURE_URL") ), therefore you need to change the following line

```
Dim StrValue As String  = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SECURE_URL"]
```

Into

```
Dim StrValue As String  = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SECURE_URL")
```

This will solve the compiler error; however, in order to make your sample work you should also change the following line

```
Response.Redirect("StrValue" + "/park/notice/payment.aspx")
```

To

```
Response.Redirect(StrValue + "/park/notice/payment.aspx")
```

This way, the value of `StrValue` is used.
In addition, you should check whether `StrValue` is Nothing (null) or empty before using its value, i.e.:

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(StrValue) Then
    Response.Redirect(StrValue + "/park/notice/payment.aspx")
End If
```

Comment: i am getting error on this part` Dim StrValue As String  = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SECURE_URL"]` about the identifer

Comment: @Abhishek: Have you added a reference to the System.configuration assembly? Is it a compiler error or an exception?

Comment: i have add that `System.configuration assembly`  that but dont know why i am getting this

Comment: @Abhishek: I've updated the sample; I think the error is in the kind of brackets you use.

Comment: thanks a small mistake make me very tens Thank u so much